# Replace multiple inheritance with composition

Tags: python, oop

Good morning,
I'm going through the book Dusty Phillips - Python 3 Object Oriented Programming - 2010 and there is task to replace multiple inheritance with composition. And so far I haven't figured out how to manage it. Someone could give me an advice or example? I don't know whether class Purchase and Rental should be located inside Property class as method or leave it outside and change something inside HouseRental etc.

```
class Property:
    def __init__(self, square_feet='', beds='', baths='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.square_feet = square_feet
        self.num_beds = beds
        self.num_baths = baths

    def display(self):
        print("PROPERTY DETAILS")
        print(f'square footage: {self.square_feet}')
        print(f'bedrooms: {self.num_beds}')
        print(f'baths: {self.num_baths}')
        print()
    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        return dict(square_feet=input("Enter the square feet: "),beds=input("Enter number of bedrooms: "),baths=input("Enter number of baths: "))


def get_valid_input(input_string, valid_option):
    input_string += ' , '.join(valid_option)
    response = input(input_string)
    while response.lower() not in valid_option:
        response = input(input_string)
    return response

class Apartment(Property):
    valid_laundries = ('coin', 'ensuite', 'none')
    valid_balconies = ('yes','no','solarium')

    def __init__(self, balcony='', laundry='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.balcony = balcony
        self.laundry = laundry

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('APARTMENT DETAILS')
        print(f'laundry {self.laundry}')
        print(f'has balcony {self.balcony}')
    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        parent_init = Property.prompt_init()
        laundry = get_valid_input("what laundry facilities does the apartment have?", Apartment.valid_laundries)
        balcony = get_valid_input('Any balcony? ',Apartment.valid_balconies)
        parent_init.update ({
            "laundry": laundry,
            "balcony": balcony
        })
        return parent_init

class House(Property):
    valid_garage = ('attached', 'detached', 'none')
    valid_fenced = ('yes', 'no')

    def __init__(self, num_stories='', garage='', fenced='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.garage = garage
        self.fenced = fenced
        self.num_stories = num_stories

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('House Details')
        print(f'# of stories: {self.num_stories}')
        print(f'garage: {self.garage}')
        print(f'fenced yard: {self.fenced}')

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        parent_init = Property.prompt_init()
        fenced = get_valid_input('Is the yard fenced? ', House.valid_fenced)
        garage = get_valid_input('Is there a garage? ', House.valid_garage)
        num_stories = input('How many stories? ')
        parent_init.update({
            "fenced": fenced,
            "garage": garage,
            "num_stories": num_stories
        })
        return parent_init

class Purchase:
    def __init__(self, price='', taxes='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.price = price
        self.taxes = taxes

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('Purchase display')
        print(f'selling price: {self.price}')
        print(f'est taxes: {self.taxes}')

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        return dict(
            price=input('What is the selling price? '),
            taxes=input('What are the est taxes? ')
        )

class Rental:
    def __init__(self, furnished='', utilities='',rent='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.furnished = furnished
        self.rent = rent
        self.utilities = utilities

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('Rental display')
        print(f'rent price: {self.rent}')
        print(f'est utilities: {self.utilities}')
        print(f'furnished: {self.furnished}')

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        return dict(
            rent=input('What is the monthly rent? '),
            utilities=input('What are the est utilities? '),
            furnished=get_valid_input('iS the property furnished? ',('yes','no')),
        )

class HouseRental(Rental, House):
    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        init = House.prompt_init()
        init.update(Rental.prompt_init())
        return init

class ApartmentRental(Rental, Apartment):
    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        init = Apartment.prompt_init()
        init.update(Rental.prompt_init())
        return init

class ApartmentPurchase(Purchase, Apartment):
    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        init = Apartment.prompt_init()
        init.update(Purchase.prompt_init())
        return init


class HousePurchase(Purchase, House):
    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        init = House.prompt_init()
        init.update(Purchase.prompt_init())
        return init

class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.property_list = []

    def display_properties(self):
        for property in self.property_list:
            property.display()

    type_map = {
        ('house', 'rental') : HouseRental,
        ('house', 'purchase') : HousePurchase,
        ('apartment', 'rental') : ApartmentRental,
        ('apartment','purchase') : ApartmentPurchase
    }

    def add_property(self):
        property_type = get_valid_input('What property? ',('house','apartment'))
        payment_type = get_valid_input('What payment type? ',("purchase", "rental"))
        PropertyClass = self.type_map[
            (property_type, payment_type)
        ]
        init_args = PropertyClass.prompt_init()
        self.property_list.append(PropertyClass(**init_args))
```

Comment: Replace `HousePurchase(Purchase, House)` by `ActionThing` and during init pass `typeSpace` and `typeSale`, where Space can be a house, flat or apartment and Sale can be purchase or rental. That also moves into the direction of Dependency Inversion (Injection).

Answer (score -1):

The `Purchase` & `Rental` are the actions performed on the `Property`. So it is always advised to add them as functions inside the `Property` class, instead of having them as separate classes.

Comment: The words "purchase" is a noun as well as a verb, and "rental" is only a noun; in this model those two classes are needed to store information about purchases and about rentals. You cannot use a function/method for the same purpose.